# PDO with JSON_INSERT to update table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, pdo

I have a class to insert, update and delete items from tables, so when using JSON_INSERT the class doesn't work properly, it gives the below error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22032]: <>: 3140 Invalid JSON text: "Missing a name for object member." at position 1 in value for column 'products.p_description'. in
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/Tests/PHP/MySQL-JSON/CRUD.php:182 Stack trace: #0
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/Tests/PHP/MySQL-JSON/CRUD.php(182): PDOStatement->execute() #1
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/Tests/PHP/MySQL-JSON/json_update.php(30):
> Database->execute() #2 {main} thrown in
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/Tests/PHP/MySQL-JSON/CRUD.php on line 182

The code I used in CRUD.php:

```
public function update($table, $fields = [], $where = null)
{
    $args    = [];
    foreach ($fields as $fk => $fv) :
        $fk = $this->strSafe($fk);
        $args[] .= $fk . ' = :' . $fk;
    endforeach;

    $sql = 'UPDATE ' . $table . ' SET ' . implode(', ', $args);

    if ($where != null) {
        $sql .= ' WHERE ' . $where;
    }

    $this->sql    = $sql;
}

public function execute()
{
    return $this->stmt->execute(); // LINE 182
}
```

To update the table field "p_description" and add a new item "chipset" with the value "Qualcomm", I used this code json_update.php:

```
$upMemList = [
    'p_description' => "JSON_INSERT(`p_description` , '$.chipset' , 'Qualcomm')"
];
$upOn = $dbh->update('products', $upMemList, 'id = :id');
$dbh->prepare($upOn);

foreach ($upMemList as $fk => $fv) :
    $dbh->bind(':' . $fk, $fv);
endforeach;
$dbh->bind('id', 1);
$dbh->execute(); // LINE 30
```

Table structure:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `p_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_description` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_cat` int NOT NULL,
  `p_price` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `p_name`, `p_description`, `p_cat`, `p_price`) VALUES
(1, 'TV1', '{\"p_usb\": \"2\", \"p_hdmi\": \"3\", \"chipset\": \"Qualcomm\", \"p_screen\": \"21\", \"resolution\": null}', 1, 3400),
(2, 'TV2', '{\"p_usb\": \"3\", \"p_hdmi\": \"3\", \"p_screen\": \"43\", \"resolution\": null}', 1, 4500),
(3, 'Computer1', '{\"p_usb\": \"2\", \"p_hdmi\": \"0\", \"chipset\": \"Qualcomm\", \"p_screen\": \"15\", \"resolution\": null}', 4, 7350),
(4, 'TV3', '{\"ports\": {\"p_usb\": \"3\", \"p_hdmi\": \"2\"}, \"p_screen\": \"65\", \"resolution\": null}', 1, 9900),
(5, 'TV4', '{\"ports\": {\"p_usb\": \"2\", \"p_hdmi\": \"2\"}, \"p_screen\": \"42\", \"resolution\": null}', 1, 3300);
```

Comment: DEBUG:101 Echo the generated query and 1) eyeball it 2) run it through phpMyAdmin or similar tool

Comment: I debug it and get the echo query, I run it through mysql command line and it works, I think something related to PHP with JSON

Comment: Method `->update()` does not return anything so `$upOn = $dbh->update('products', $upMemList, 'id = :id');` will set `$upOn` to FALSE

Comment: adding the `echo 'upOn '.print_r($upOn).'<br>';` returns "1"

Comment: In my opinion wrapping a perfectly good Object (PDO) in another object only adds confusion and unnecessary complexity and also makes it difficult for someone else to maintain the code where a well documentated and known Object (PDO) would not cause any of these issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `update` method does not return a value, but places the query in a property try this

```
$upMemList = [
    'p_description' => "JSON_INSERT(`p_description` , '$.chipset' , 'Qualcomm')"
];

$dbh->update('products', $upMemList, 'id = :id');
$dbh->prepare($dbh->sql);

foreach ($upMemList as $fk => $fv) :
    $dbh->bind(':' . $fk, $fv);
endforeach;
$dbh->bind('id', 1);
$dbh->execute(); // LINE 30
```

Or alternatively, as the query is already a property of the class, change the `prepare()` method to use `$this->sql` and prepare that

As some of your rows contain a `chipset` already and others dont I think you would do better using `JSON_SET()` which inserts or updates data in a JSON document and returns the result.

```
$upMemList = [
    'p_description' => "JSON_SET(`p_description` , '$.chipset' , 'Qualcomm')"
];
```

Comment: it returns this error `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22032]: <<Unknown error>>: 3140 Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in value for column 'products.p_description'`

Comment: Yes, I faced this error before removing the return `$this->sql` from CRUD file

Comment: Can you add the schema for this table to your question

Comment: I added the table structure and some inserts, I imported from TablePlus

Comment: FWIW, in current versions of PHP, you don't need the leading `:` when you bind parameters. You need it in the SQL query, but not when you bind.

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin didnt want to change too much specially as the `bind()` method is not on show

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin, I removed the leading `:`, still having the same error

Comment: Did you try using a `JSON_SET()` as I suggested at the end of the answer?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I used JSON_SET, I've got the same error, however if I change the sentence to `$upMemList = ['p_description' => '{"chipset": "SN"}'];`, it update the column, removes the old records and update with the new one, so may be the problem is coming from JSON_INSERT itself